# Different Insets for different UICollectionView in the same XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have multiple `UICollectionView` controls in my view. Each them have different numbers of items, some have enough to fill the width of screen but some of them only have handful if items which cannot fill the width of screen. For the second group of `UICollectionView`s I want to horizontally centre the content:

[image]

This function sets the layout for the `UICollectionView`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    var cellWidth : CGFloat = 110

    var numberOfCells = floor(self.view.frame.size.width / cellWidth)
    var edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * cellWidth)) / (numberOfCells + 1)

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)
}
```

My question is how can I get the **cell width** of each `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Do you want to keep the ItemWidth constant and centre the contents horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

In order to centre the items in collectionView when number of items is less. Use the below code

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
var insets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

var collectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout = collectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout
var itemWidth = collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize.width
var itemSpacing = collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

// Change this to the number of items in section
var numOfItem : CGFloat = 2
var totalWidth = (numOfItem * itemWidth) + (numOfItem - 1 ) * itemSpacing;

if (totalWidth < collectionView.frame.size.width)
{
    insets.left = (collectionView.frame.size.width - totalWidth) * 0.5 - itemSpacing;
}

return insets;

}
```

Comment: I hope you notice i'm using Swift

Comment: @AshishKakkad sorry, `;` fixed

Answer (score 0):

Since only the number of cells are variable, this trick worked:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    var cellWidth : CGFloat = 110;

    var numberOfCells = floor(screenSize.width / cellWidth)
    var edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * cellWidth)) / (numberOfCells + 1)

    if(collectionView == alignmentsCV){
        //alignmentCV cell size is 50x50
        cellWidth = 50

        var numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0)
        println(numberOfItems)
        println(screenSize.width)
        var wholeItemsWidth = CGFloat(numberOfItems) * cellWidth
        println(wholeItemsWidth)
        if wholeItemsWidth < screenSize.width {
            var freeSpace : CGFloat = (screenSize.width - wholeItemsWidth) / 2

            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, freeSpace , 0, freeSpace)

        }else{
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)
        }

    }else{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]